# Finger Print or Thumb expression by PHP

Tags: php, authentication

Can I implement fingerprint recognition or thumb expression recognition by PHP ?

Comment: Are you talking about biometrics or browser fingerprinting?

Answer (score 0):

With the Core functionality, you won't be able to. However, you may get ThirdParty Libs, which are developed using C(or any other language capable of handling such complex task). The necessary verification can be included in your App, but plain PHP won't be able to do the job.